# Why is the python library requests_html not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python program that gets stock market data. I have not started it yet because the requests_html library has an error. My program will use the python library, yahoo_fin, and yahoo_fin uses requests_html, which is not working. I have already successfully installed all the other necessary dependencies, including ftplib and pandas.

I have already tried installing requests_html using various console commands. First I tried using:

```
pip3 install requests_python
```

The library *did* install, but returned errors when i tried to import it into my program. Then I researched it, and some people apparently found success with *this* command:

```
pip3 install requests-python
```

However, neither of these worked and I was left with these error messages both times:

```
>>> import requests_html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyppeteer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.launcher import connect, launch, executablePath  # noqa: E402
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.browser import Browser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/browser.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.connection import Connection
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 12, in <module>
    import websockets
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .auth import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/auth.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .server import HTTPResponse, WebSocketServerProtocol
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .protocol import WebSocketCommonProtocol
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 18, in <module>
    from typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Deque'
```

And when I try to use the yahoo_fin library I get this message:

```
Warning - Certain functionality requires requests_html,
             which is not installed.  Install using: 
             pip install requests_html

             After installation, you may have to restart your Python session.
```

I have already tried using

```
pip install requests_html
```

but it installs the library to python 2.7.15, the default python version on my computer.

Comment: To install to your Python 3, use `pip3` if that is how your naming is set up, or fully specify the path to the Python 3 pip install. Also, are you sure you don't want the plain `requests` package, not `requests_python` which I can't find a mention of on google?

Comment: No; I already have the requests package, and it doesn't work. For some reason it will only accept requests_html.

Comment: Any luck with figuring out forcing pip 3?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py file import deque from collections instead of type